# Латинские названия месяцев

Tags: лексика, заимствования, история

Когда и почему в русском языке была принята латинская система названий месяцев?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Х веке **с принятием христианства** на Русь пришло летосчисление, применявшееся римлянами и византийцами: юлианский календарь, римские названия месяцев, семидневная неделя.

Но счет годов велся от сотворения мира, которое произошло за 5508 лет до Рождества Христова. Год начинался с 1 марта, а в конце XV века начало года было перенесено на 1 сентября.
Действовавший в России календарь от «сотворения мира» заменил  на  юлианский Пётр I с 1 января 1700 года (разница между двумя системами летоисчисления составляет 5508 лет).

Почему - понятно, потому что если приняли христианство, нужно быть последовательными и принимать весь календарь,  ведь христианские праздники должны совпадать, значит, и месяцы должны совпадать.

Довольно долго славянские и латинские названия сосуществовали в устной речи и светской письменности(бытовых письмах, торговых документах). С XII века наряду с народными названиями месяцев в церковных книгах появляются и новые, заимствованные из латинского языка через греческий. Они совсем чужие, произносятся на иноземный лад: януарий, фебруар (или февру-арь) , марот, априль, май, иунь, нуль, аугуст, сентемврий, октемврий, новембар, декембар.

Даже образованные люди не всегда могли бы понять, о каких месяцах идет речь. Поэтому в рукописных книгах, не жалея драгоценного места на пергаменте, писцы заботливо поясняют: «месяц януарь рекомый просинец, месяц октемврий рекше листопадъ» , что значит: январь, называемый просинцем, октябрь, то есть листопад.

Такие пояснения встречаются вплоть до XVII века, при этом и формулировки перевода на обычные названия не меняются, пишут рекомый, рекше, позже также и сиречь (так сказать) .

А вот уже сиречь — характерная примета нового отношения к заимствованным словам. Прежде отталкивались от славянских названий, славянским словом поясняли новое: «декемъбар, рекомый студеный» (декабрь, по-нашему называемый студеный) .

Теперь, с XV века, меняется и произношение этих чужих слов, и отношение к ним. Декабрь сиречь студеный буквально значит декабрь, то есть студеный. Это уже не перевод одной системы обозначений в другую, более привычную, а соотнесение двух равноправных систем, одинаково известных и одинаково важных. А тем временем все сложные сочетания звуков в заимствованных словах изменились на русский образец, некоторые слова сократились: например, сентябрь вместо сентемврий.

Они стали осознаваться как вполне русские слова, в них даже стали выделять русские суффиксы: -арь в слове январь — по аналогии с пах-арь, -аль в феврале по примеру невид-алъ. Таким образом, из чудных варваризмов превратились эти слова в русские.

Когда же в конце XVII века соединились и государственные интересы России, и необходимость выйти на мировую торговую и экономическую арену, и образование единого русского литературного языка на национальной, русской основе, и распадение старых, сугубо крестьянских представлений о течении времени, когда все это сплелось в один сложный узел событий, — тогда потребовалась одна-единственная система обозначений, общая для всех и связанная с тою, которой пользовались во всей Европе.

И по многим причинам победила переводная, книжная система, она стала русской литературной системой. Вторая, ставшая теперь  неважной, постепенно распалась.

Comment: Спасибо! Но ведь и после принятия христианства продолжали существовать славянские названия месяцев. Как так вышло? Они именно сосуществовали с заимствованными? Или существовало разграничение по сферам применения?

Comment: Да, они сосуществовали довольно долго. Подробнее добавлю в ответ